# What safeguards are in place on a seedship fleet to ensure that all eventual crew members are interested in the mission?

Tags: space-travel

Knowing that a journey to Some Star would take too long for a fully trained crew to survive, and in the absence of suspended animation, we have decided to send a ship with embryos on board.  Once they are forty years out, the embryos will be allowed to grow and will be raised on board the ship by automated caregivers.  These caregivers are also responsible for training the crew.  It's such an important mission that all hands have to be on deck here, and every eventual crew member has to be fully dedicated to training, fully on board for the mission, and fully OK with not being able to return.

What needs to be programmed into the care givers so that every crew member turns out the way they need to in order to fulfill the mission?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question offhand, but if you get a good one I'll be watching for it because I have a few teenagers I'd like to apply the answer to IRL.

Comment: In order for this to be answered, I think you need to clarify what technological (not just biotech but also sociotech, emotitech & spiritech) expectations you have in this setting. Off hand, I'd say your crew is 100% f\/cked because they have no humans from which to learn to become human beings. I'd suspect your poor robots will end up with a shipload of psychotic, emotionally crippled, hyperrandily peripubescent little thickheads.  Think *Lord of the Flies* but in space and with girls thrown into the mix.  Good basis, but right now, I think your query might be a little too broad.

Comment: That's actually a very good point.  Humans learn to be human from other humans.  I shall think about it further

Comment: Is it possible to answer this question?  Every parent who has had a child turn away from their beliefs, hopes, and dreams (and almost every parent falls into this category) would love to know what magic bullet would solve this problem.  However, I'm positive that there's one (if not all) psychologist out there who is absolutely sure they know the answer - as long as there's enough counseling involved.

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is that the embryos (the actual reason for the trip) are entrusted to automation to keep safe and raise.  So what purpose is the crew serving, as surely automation could do what's need, possibly better than humans  (who are, after all, rather fragile, delicate things by machine standards :-) ) ?

Comment: of course, it's survival. The onboard generation won't survive unless they accept their training & continue with the mission. The human species has had enormous experience with & practice in indoctrinating successive generations to absorb their culture. The onboard culture will be to be its crew. Otherwise they all die. Death is a great incentive to good behaviour.

Comment: If your automated system is capable of doing all this, then it is also likely capable or running the ship and going most of the grunt work once they are on the planet. Robots don't need rest, they don't need food, or bathroom breaks. They just need power. If you need them to teach someone something, especially physically, because your raising children who mimic, then you might as well make them perform the task.

Comment: @a4android *"Death is a great incentive to good behavior"*  We've been executing people for various crimes for as long as human history records (and presumably before that too) and yet the same crimes keep happening, so death isn't as great an incentive as you may think.  Also remember that people commit suicide and even murder-suicides, not to mention fanatics that think killing everyone (including themselves) is actually a reasonable solution.

Comment: @StephenG You're misreading how death leads to good behaviour. What I am suggesting is how it influences people who want to stay alive not those who see death as a means to an end..Avoiding dying is important to reasonable people. Spacecraft can be dangerous & making sure they run well is important to the crew.

Comment: @a4android *"reasonable people"* It is not possible to *guarantee* that everyone will be reasonable.  You can, incidentally, guarantee (to a higher standard) that the machines will be reasonable in performing their routine duties during the voyage, so the weak link is the people, IMO.

Comment: @StephenG If your reasoning wasn't so simplistic you would realize it isn't necessary that everybody is reasonable just enough of them to prevent the unreasonable ones causing harm. This is how societies function despite carrying their fair share of maniacs and incompetents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a start, your robots need to appear perfectly human. This will be essential to the infants learning to mimic them. Furthermore, given what we know about lingual development, it will be necessary for the caretakers to communicate with each other in spoken language; infants not only absorb vocabulary through repeated exposure, they develop the neural pathways necessary to understand grammar and differentiate beyond phonemes.

Now, besides the basic functions of the caretakers, we have a few concerns. If we want a viable colony, we'll need a population that can interbreed. This means raising the children in small social circles, at least initially; if we don't isolate them sufficiently from each other, Westermarck Effect takes hold, if we have too large groups, we'll see tribal rivalry when they're introduced into a shared environment. So we'll need about a one-to-one ratio of caretakers and crew. We then need to ensure the health of the entire crew: unfortunately, we have no way of doing this in real life as of yet, so some handwaving about advanced genetic engineering is probably in order. Finally, we need motivation. This shouldn't be as hard as it may seem; simple rewarding of behaviour is enough to keep someone on task, especially if they're unfamiliar with other options. Tying regulation of nutrition to performance in training should suffice, provided the poorest performance doesn't result in long-term damage via malnutrition. Keeping them happy at this shouldn't be too difficult either; they'll need some superficial choices to feel fulfilled, but that can be solved by providing some slightly different means of accomplishing their work. For bonus motivation, give them a high-score board for similar tasks.

**TL;DR: Raise them like a gamified elementary school.**

Comment: Sounds like much hassle and handwaving (especially perfect robots part), generation ship should be easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. But you can lower the chances to 1. Your seedship is North Korea. Or some Eskimo village in desolated cold Canada. There will always be someone who would rather to other things than what they are told to do. That's human nature and thanks to it we made discoveries. And loss of part of the crew should be calculated in general population. You cannot have population "just enough". You need to calculate death, sickness and desertion.
How can you lower those chances to minimum? First remove anything they can get back to. Tell there is no Earth. Or the Earth is not worth coming back (just play mainstream news from the past 2 months to them).
Second - find them things they can think they came up with themselves. Maybe you designated person to be janitor, they are rebelling so you "suggest" they try being inventor.
Third - don't treat it as a mission. Manipulate them to think that it's their purpose to do such things. Create something like religion. A cult of maintaining the ship and doing things that are written in Big Book of Bob. OF course it's the first thing that will backfire but that is not your problem.

Comment: "A cult of maintaining the ship"? This idea gets Adeptus Mechanicus seal of approval.

Answer (score 1):

**Upload/Download Minds**

With Joss Whedon's [Dollhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollhouse_(TV_series)), the inhabitants have their memories, personalities and skills uploaded, downloaded and edited as needed.

If while growing your crew, you also load in memories and skills, you can create the individuals you want instead of leaving it to chance.

Comment: Seems simpler to build robots.

Comment: Maybe but said crew can repopulate the destination which is the whole point of the seed ship.

Comment: Building robots does seem simpler. I can't reconcile the sophistication of the care givers with the question "why not just program them to be scientists instead of child minders?". It is possible that this story won't make sense.

Comment: Well the point of a seed ship is to populate the planet. At some point a robot needs to raise a baby