# The galaxy is our nursery

Tags: space-colonization, engineering

**My question:**

***Given that all of the technology I describe actually exists, what would be the most significant risks for the space-colonization project described below?***

**The Project:**

A group of wealthy businesspeople start up a space colonisation project right now based on the following ideas:

- Sending small spacecraft in the direction of the nearest ‘human
  habitable’ planets, carrying frozen sperm/eggs and suitable
  technology/robots for carrying out the the initial steps I describe
  below. They don’t expect any significant breakthroughs in propulsion
  to occur anytime soon, so the whole setup is designed to last a
  journey of tens of thousands of years, and to be able to activate the
  relevant systems when it finally reaches its target planet.
- Once the spacecraft has reached the planet and landed at an
  appropriate site, some of the robots will erect a small habitat to act
  as a ‘nursery’.
- Within this nursery, and using artificial womb technology, the frozen
  sperm and eggs will be used to product human children, who will
  subsequently be nurtured, fed and given a relevant education until
  they are old enough to be self-sufficient - these responsibilities
  will be carried out by robotic ‘nannies’. Robots will also be
  responsible for the growth of food crops.
- 3 separate ‘eras’ of children will be planned, each of which will
  fulfil a certain responsibility.
- Era 1: Will be responsible for constructing a ‘town’ beyond the
  nursery, for later eras to inhabit. Era 1 will consist solely of
  males born via the artificial wombs, from sperm/egg donors with
  proven skill in construction and engineering work.
- Era 2: Will be responsible for rapid increase of the population base
  and genetic variation within the ‘town’ population. Era 2 will
  consist solely of females, initial generations being born
  artificially, subsequent generations being born from via implanting
  of embryos in living women, and the later generations being born from
  insemination of the women with the frozen sperm.
- Era 3: Will be released into the wild. Era 3 will consist of both
  males and females. The first generation will be produced by
  insemination of women with the frozen sperm and subsequent
  generations will be produced ‘the normal way’. There is now a
  population of thousands of humans going forth into a new world to
  fend for themselves… wish them luck.

*Thanks in advance for your input!*

Comment: Have done. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Do you make any assumptions about availability of human-habitable planets?

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  I've retracted my vote.  Please note that your question would be improved still if you could explain what "most significant" means.  That's the basic problem with "primarily opinion-based," we don't know how you will judge the best answer.  An example would be, "no more than 10% casualties."  Limitations that bound the problem so that we avoid the "infinite number of answers and each is valid" condition (see [help/dont-ask] for more details).

Comment: Have you considered the psychological effects of being raised by robots, and then living in a single sex society? If one could ensure all of the individuals in a given 'era' were homosexual, some of it could be mitigated, but I suspect humans are going to experience serious psychological harm regardless.

Comment: Someone just asked a question like this in the last week or so.  I recall mentioning the likely social and mental problems the humans will suffer, not being raised by humans.

Comment: [Here's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148039/what-safeguards-are-in-place-on-a-seedship-fleet-to-ensure-that-all-eventual-cre) the previous one, answers might be of interest.

Comment: @Alexander , here are some things I might assume about the planets:

1. There are many human-habitable planets in the universe, but the closest take tens of thousands of years travel to reach.
2. We know where the planets are, the composition of their atmosphere and surface, their movement in space and can make a good guess at their overall climate. 
3. We don't know finer details like the features on their surface or presence of lifeforms.
4. A human-habitable planet would easily be able to support other forms of life.
5. There is probably oxygen-producing vegetation on the planet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The unexpected**

This might sound like a glib answer, but it isn’t. The biggest failure point in your mission (and one I personally think would be an odd-on bet to happen) is that something occurs that your automated systems are unequipped to handle.

Machines are bad at improvisational problem solving. Any issues along the way that don’t fit into their parameters for ‘This is problem X, I solve it using algorithm Y’ will quickly snowball into a catalogue of errors that the machines can’t stop. This is a risk at every point of the journey, especially when it comes to landing and trying to grow food on an unknown planet. All it takes is for the local soil to foul-up your PH sensors (for example) and suddenly the computerised farming bot is just an expensive roomba.

If your engineers have thought of *every* conceivable scenario and coded for it then this risk is gone, but we’re talking about an unknown planet and rearing an entire generation of children with no human contact. The unexpected is guaranteed.

If your code is adaptive enough to identify and respond to unknown issues at the level you’d require to make this work then frankly it’s sapient and it can dispense with the squishy meat sacks. They’re just a source of hard to quantify errors anyway.

Comment: Excellent comment. During the development phase of the project on Earth, they may be able to test the robots and other equipment in plenty of different scenarios, but they can't really know what new surprises will await them on the surface.

Answer (score 3):

Your particular scenario:  Robots smart enough to grow and raise children from zygotes won't require era 1.  If you look at the settlement of the American and Canadian west, the population doubling time is a fraction of a generation.  This would be even truer if you had even modest medical help.  Add to this robot production machinery, a comprehensive electronic library with an AI librarian to help find things in it.

If your machinery is sufficiently robust, it creates a population of 10-20 thousand individuals, popping them out of artifician wombs as fast as possible, then, at the end, harvesting some eggs and sperm, and departing for the next planet.  The pause at each planet would be small compared to the voyage time.  Call it 50 years per stop:  Raise a generation, teach them, get them to repair anything that the internal robots can't do on the ship.  Meanwhile, ship scouts for new target stars.

Cut the journey time, and you have James Hogan's "Voyage from Yesteryear"

Hogan addresses some of the issues of a tribe of kids raised by smart robots, and creates a world in a post scarcity economy.

Wikipedia plot summary:

> The story opens early in the 21st century, as an automated space probe is being prepared for a mission to explore habitable exoplanets in the Alpha Centauri system. However, Earth appears destined for a global war which the probe designers fear that humanity may not survive. It appears that the only chance for the human species is to reestablish itself far away from the conflict but there is no time left for a manned expedition to escape Earth. The team, led by Henry B. Congreve, change their mission priority and quickly modify the design to carry several hundred sets of electronically coded human genetic data. Also included in this mission of embryo space colonization is a databank of human knowledge, robots to convert the data into genetic material and care for the children and construct habitats when the destination is reached, and a number of artificial wombs. The probe's designers name it the Kuan-Yin after the bodhisattva of childbirth and compassion.
>
> Shortly after the launch, global war indeed breaks out and several decades later, Earthbound humanity is united under an authoritarian government. It is this government that receives a radio message from the fledgling "Chironian" civilization revealing that the probe found a habitable planet (Chiron) and that the first generation of children have been raised successfully.
>
> As the surviving power blocs of Earth before the conflict are still evident, North America, Europe and Asia each send a generation ship to Alpha Centauri to take control of the colony. By the time that the first generation ship (the American Mayflower II) arrives after 20 years, Chironian society is in its fifth generation.
>
> The Mayflower II has brought with it thousands of settlers, all the trappings of the authoritarian regime along with bureaucracy, religion, fascism and a military presence to keep the population in line. However, the planners behind the generation ship did not anticipate the direction that Chironian society took: in the absence of conditioning and with limitless robotic labor and fusion power, Chiron has become a post-scarcity economy. Money and material possessions are meaningless to the Chironians and social standing is determined by individual talent, which has resulted in a wealth of art and technology without any hierarchies, central authority or armed conflict.
>
> In an attempt to crush this anarchist adhocracy, the Mayflower II government employs every available method of control; however, in the absence of conditioning the Chironians are not even capable of comprehending the methods, let alone bowing to them. The Chironians simply use methods similar to Gandhi's satyagraha and other forms of nonviolent resistance to win over most of the Mayflower II crew members, who had never previously experienced true freedom, and isolate the die-hard authoritarians.
>
> Frustrated with their lack of success, the authoritarian faction stages a military coup on board the Mayflower II and launches the ship's heavily armed "battle module", threatening to attack unless they submit to a military dictatorship. Having isolated the authoritarians, the Chironians destroy the module with an antimatter particle beam weapon. The remainder of the crew dissolve their government and join Chironian society. The week after, the laser communications beam to the Mayflower II cuts off, having been destroyed in another global war that had taken place 4.5 years ago.
>
> The epilogue is set five years after these events and shows that the Chironians also assimilated the crews of the Asian and European starships. Now united, the Chironians refit and recommission the Mayflower II with an advanced antimatter drive and rename it the Henry B. Congreve. The Henry B. Congreve is sent back to Earth to rebuild human civilization (with the new drive, this journey will only take eight years), fulfilling the Kuan-Yin's mission of preserving humanity.

Comment: -1 There is a book with a plot similar to the OP question. Okay. But it doesn't answer the OP question: what are the difficulties this plot is going to have. The book is a soft-scifi focused on politics which handwaves any physics, biologic, economic or even logic problems that would actually arise.

Answer (score 2):

**Alien Predators !!**

The planet is habitable right and its really far away, so you don't have the surety if there is Alien life or not.

This alien life doesn't need to be intelligent like humans, just predators like Lions, tigers or wolves (of course they would look different but will have predatory nature).
These predators may cut down your numbers significantly.

If the alien life is intelligent like cavemen, the things get complicated.

So, during the training and education part of your Era 1, you have to take care of giving proper training for combat, hunting, defenses, weapon handling (swords, knives, spears, guns, etc.).
However, things could also get out of hand during the process when your robots are erecting the habitats and giving training.

**Food**

If you are planning on a vegetarian diet on an alien planet, take some things into account.

The crops that can be grown on earth may not grow on another planet or

If your plans are to eat the local crops, they might simply be poisonous to a human being.

So your humans may simply starve after your ships ration is finished.

**Planet's Weather**

If it's too harsh for your robots or Eras to perform their tasks, its gonna be a problem.
Unpredictable rains, dust storms, cyclones, or whatever, if you don't take them into account, your settlement schedule may fall apart.